# Sum of the squares of the reciprocals of the fixed points of the tangent function

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, residue-calculus

The sum of the squares of the reciprocals of the positive fixed points of the tangent function is $1/10$.

I've seen this proved by means of residues, but I don't remember the details.

I've also heard it asserted that it that it can be done by means of Green's functions.

What proofs of this fact are published or otherwise known?

**PS:** Maybe it is of interest to note that the positive fixed points of the tangent function are also the abscissas of the extreme values of the function $x\mapsto\dfrac{\sin x} x.$

Comment: Have you seen [Mahajan's treatment](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/full_pdfs/Street-Fighting_Mathematics.pdf)? (See page 113.)

Comment: Looks like this question has been on your mind for a long time :-) http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=1612788&tstart=19545

Comment: I think it was _after_ that time that I saw it done by residues.  And as I said, I've forgotten the details.

Comment: Relevant: https://groups.google.com/group/sci.math.symbolic/browse_thread/thread/c5b555272d9aca60/36a1b0fe634037cc?hl=en (there's Robert Israel 6 years ago) and http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1971-25-116/S0025-5718-1971-0304726-X/S0025-5718-1971-0304726-X.pdf and http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~saito/publications/saito_rayleighfunc.pdf.

Comment: The book by Mahajan is a pure marvel. Unfortunately, the link given by @J. M. is broken. See now (https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/titles/free_download/9780262514293_Street_Fighting_Mathematics.pdf)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For the sake of at least having an answer, here's what's in J.M.'s link, in a nutshell anyway.

Note that $\tan(x)-x$ and $\sin(x)-x\cos(x)$ have the same zeros but the latter is holomorphic on the complex plane - the difference is that the latter has a triple root at $0$ whereas the former only has a double root, but our sum doesn't involve $x=0$ anyway. This means it affords a [Weierstrass factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem). Some work can show that the coefficients of the expanded-out polynomials of the partial products in such a factorization will, in the limit, converge to those of the Taylor expansion of the function so long as we ignore the $e^{g(z)}$ and $E_n(z)$ factors. We can also show that the zeros are approximately $x_n\approx(n+\frac{1}{2})\pi$ asymptotically, and comparing this with the factorization for, say, $\sin$ tells us we don't need any $E_n$ factors. Now putting together the series expansions for sine and cosine gives

$$\left(x-\frac{1}{3!}x^3+\frac{1}{5!}x^5-\cdots\right)-x\left(1-\frac{1}{2!}x^2+\frac{1}{4!}x^4-\cdots\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{3}x^3\left(1-\frac{1}{10}x^2+\cdots\right).$$

We ignore the $x^3$ and normalize so that $a_0=1,a_1=0,a_2=-1/10$. Now compute

$$\sum_{\tan(u)=u\ne0}u^{-2}=\left(\sum_{i}\frac{1}{\lambda_i}\right)^2-2\left(\sum_{i<j}\frac{1}{\lambda_i\lambda_j}\right)$$

$$=a_1^2-2a_2=\frac{1}{5}.$$

Note that $\tan(x)-x$ is an odd function and squaring takes out signs so by symmetry the above sum essentially double-counts every positive root. Divide by $2$ and our final answer is $1/10$.

Note that all sums-of-reciprocals of *even* powers of solutions to $\tan(x)=x$ can be evaluated in this way by using the [Newton-Girard formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities).

Comment: Did you define the $\lambda$s somewhere?

Comment: @Michael: Eh, not explicitly I guess. They're the nonzero roots of $\tan u=u$ of course.

Comment: @anon: Recently I happened to ask the same question on MSE and was directed to your answer. I think that this method needs some sort of justification because we are not dealing with roots of polynomials. Also if we consider $\lambda$'s to be root of $\tan u = u$ then $\sum 1/\lambda_{i}$ diverges and hence can't be squared in the last step.

Comment: @Paramanand Those are both good points. Both points are already engaged with in my answer: *"Some work can show that the coefficients of the expanded-out polynomials of the partial products in such a factorization will, in the limit, converge to those of the Taylor expansion of the function."*

Answer (score 5):

Here is a very different proof :

Let $0 < x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < \cdots $ be the positive roots of equation

$$\tan(x)=x \tag 0$$

These roots are such that

$$\sin(x_k)= x_k \cos(x_k) \tag 1 $$

(this relationship will be used later on).

We have to show that :

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x_k^2}=\frac{1}{10} \tag 2$$

The framework is Hilbert space $L^2[0,1]$ of square integrable functions on $[0,1]$ with bilinear form $\langle f|g\rangle:=\int_0^1fg$.

Let us consider its closed subspace defined by

$$E=\{f\mid f(0)=0 \ \ \& \ \ f(1)=f'(1) \ \ \& f \in C^2\}, \tag 3 $$

itself a Hilbert space.

Operator $\Delta : f \mapsto f''$ is a self-adjoint operator on $E$, due to the fact that a double integration by parts gives :

$$\int f g'' = \int f'' g \ \ \iff \ \ \langle f|\Delta g \rangle=\langle \Delta f| g \rangle \tag 4 $$

The kernel of $\Delta$ is one-dimensional : it is the set of linear functions $f(x)=ax$. Let $\varphi_0(x)=x$ be the basis of this kernel.

Functions defined by $\varphi_k(x)=\sin(x_kx)$ (with $x_k$ as defined in (2)), due to property (1), belong to space $E$ and moreover are such that :

$$\Delta \varphi_k = x_k^2 \varphi_k \tag 5 $$

i.e., they are eigenvectors of operator $\Delta$ with associated eigenvalues $x_k^2$.

Their norms are found to be

$$\|\varphi_0\|^2=\frac{1}{3} \ \ \text{and} \ \ \|\varphi_k\|^2=\frac{1}{2}\sin^2(x_k)\tag{6}$$

Being eigenvectors of a self-adjoint operator, functions $\varphi_k$ are mutually orthogonal. We admit that they constitute an Hilbert basis of $E$, allowing us to write, for any $f \in E$ :

$$f=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\|\varphi_k\|^2} \langle f
\mid \varphi_k \rangle\tag{7}$$

Now consider the particular function $f(x)=x^3-2x^2 \in E$.

We have the following chain of equalities :

- in the case [$k>0$] :

$$\langle f\mid \varphi_k \rangle=\langle f\mid \frac{1}{x_k^2}\Delta\varphi_k \rangle=\frac{1}{x_k^2}\langle \Delta f\mid\varphi_k \rangle=\frac{1}{x_k^2}(-6\langle \varphi_0 \mid \varphi_k \rangle+  \langle 4\mid\varphi_k \rangle) = \frac{4}{x_k^2}(1-\cos(x_k))\tag{8}$$

- in the case [$k=0$] :

$$\langle f\mid \varphi_0 \rangle=\int_0^1 x(x^3-2x^2) \, dx=-\tfrac{3}{10}\tag{9}$$

Now, using (7)

$$f(x):=x^3-2x^2=-\frac{9}{10}x+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{8}{x_k^2(1+\cos(x_k))}\sin(x_kx)\tag{10}$$

Let us terminate by computing, thanks to (10), the expression  $f'(0)+f'(1)$ in two ways (with the LHS and the RHS), from which we deduce (2).

Answer (score 4):

I answered [this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2921750) a while ago, so I thought I would answer this question in the same manner, with more detail.

---

**Residue at $\boldsymbol{z=0}$**

Compute the series near $x=0$ for $\tan(x)$ as the ratio of the series for $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$:
$$
\begin{align}
\tan(x)
&=\frac{x-\frac16x^3+\frac1{120}x^5+O\!\left(x^7\right)}{1-\frac12x^2+\frac1{24}x^4+O\!\left(x^6\right)}\\
&=\left(x-\frac16x^3+\frac1{120}x^5+O\!\left(x^7\right)\right)\left(1+\frac12x^2+\frac5{24}x^4+O\!\left(x^6\right)\right)\\
&=x+\frac13x^3+\frac2{15}x^5+O\!\left(x^7\right)\tag1
\end{align}
$$
compute the series near $x=0$ for $\frac1{\tan(x)-x}$ using $(1)$:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{\tan(x)-x}
&=\frac1{\frac13x^3+\frac2{15}x^5+O\!\left(x^7\right)}\\
&=\frac3{x^3}\left(1-\frac25x^2+O\!\left(x^4\right)\right)\\
&=\frac3{x^3}-\frac6{5x}+O(x)\tag2
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$\newcommand{\Res}{\operatorname*{Res}}
\Res_{z=0}\left(\frac1{\tan(z)-z}\right)=-\frac65\tag3
$$

---

**Residue at Other Singularities**

At any point $z_k\ne0$ where $\tan(z_k)=z_k$,
$$
\begin{align}
\Res_{z=z_k}\frac1{\tan(z)-z}
&=\lim_{z\to z_k}\frac{z-z_k}{\tan(z)-z}\\
&=\lim_{z\to z_k}\frac1{\sec^2(z)-1}\\
&=\frac1{\tan^2(z_k)}\\
&=\frac1{z_k^2}\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Enumerate the positive roots of $\tan(z)=z$ as $\{z_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$. Note that $\{-z_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ are the negative roots of $\tan(z)=z$.

---

**Behavior Near $\boldsymbol{\infty}$**

Since $\tan(n\pi+iy)=i\tanh(y)$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, we get that
$$\newcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}\newcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}
\begin{align}
|\tan(n\pi+iy)|
&=|\tanh(y)|\\
\le1\tag5
\end{align}
$$
and 
$$
\begin{align}
|\tan(x+iy)|
&=\left|\frac{e^{ix-y}-e^{-ix+y}}{e^{ix-y}+e^{-ix+y}}\right|\\
&\le\left|\frac{\cosh(y)}{\sinh(y)}\right|\\
&=|\coth(y)|\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Thus, on the path $\max(|\Re(z)|,|\Im(z)|)=n\pi$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, we have
$$
|\tan(z)|\le\coth(\pi)\tag7
$$
Thus, on that path
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{\tan(z)-z}
&=\frac1{O(1)-z}\\
&=-\frac1z+O\!\left(\frac1{z^2}\right)\tag8
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the integral counter-clockwise around that path is $-2\pi i$.

---

**The Sum**

Putting $(3)$, $(4)$, and $(8)$ together, we get
$$
-2\pi i=2\pi i\left(-\frac65+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{z_k^2}\right)\tag9
$$
which gives
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{z_k^2}=\frac1{10}\tag{10}
$$

Answer (score 2):

The answer I got was not $\frac{1}{10}$ so it is likely that I have made a mistake somewhere.

$$x=\tan x$$

$$x^{2}\cos^{2}{x} =\sin^{2}{x}$$

$$x^{2}(1-\frac{x^{2}}{2!}+\frac{x^{4}}{4!}+\cdots)^{2}=(x-\frac{x^{3}}{3!}+\frac{x^{5}}{5!}+\cdots)^{2}$$

$$x^{2}-x^{4}+\frac{x^{6}}{4}+\frac{x^{6}}{12}-\frac{x^{8}}{24}+\cdots=x^{2}-\frac{x^{4}}{3}+\frac{x^{6}}{36}+\frac{x^{6}}{60}+\cdots$$

$t=x^{2}$

$$t^{2}(\frac{2}{3}-\frac{13t}{45}+\cdots)=0$$

In a polynomial of the form $a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^{n}$ with roots $x_1,\ldots,x_n$,  $\frac{a_0}{a_n}=x_{1}x_{2}\cdots$ and $\frac{a_2}{a_n}=-x_3x_4x_5-\cdots-x_1x_4-\cdots-x_1x_2x_5-\cdots-x_2x_4x_5-\cdots-\cdots$

If the root with $t=0$ is excluded, the sum of the reciprocals $=\frac{\frac{13}{45}}{\frac{2}{3}}=\frac{13}{30}$. $\tan{-x}=-\tan{x}$ therefore the reciprocal sums of positive and negative sums are equal, so for positive roots the sum is $\frac{13}{60}$.

Comment: The question is "sums of *squares* of reciprocals..."

Answer (score 2):

I just saw a link here, so here's a solution of mine that dates back to 2008. Original version in this [AoPS thread](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h182057_sum_of_the_series), which also includes the Weierstrass factorization solution. The solution here is modified from the original, most importantly by using a different contour so I don't have to worry about a principal value at a 3rd order pole.

Consider the function
$$f(z)=\frac{\sin z}{z(\sin z-z\cos z)}=\frac{1}{z-z^2\cot z}$$
This function has simple poles at $z=x_n$ for nonzero roots $x_n=\tan x_n$ with residue $\frac{\sin x_n}{x_n}\cdot \frac1{x_n\sin x_n}=\frac1{x_n^2}$. Note that this residue is the same at the positive root $x_n$ and the negative root $-x_n$. It also has a third-order pole at $z=0$, where $f$ has Laurent series expansion
\begin{align*}f(z) &= \frac1{z-z^2\frac{1-\frac12z^2+\frac1{24}z^4+\cdots}{z-\frac16z^3+\frac1{120}z^5+\cdots}}=\frac{z-\frac16z^3+\frac1{120}z^5+\cdots}{z^2-\frac16z^4+\frac1{120}z^6-z^2+\frac12z^4-\frac1{24}z^6+\cdots}\\
&= \frac{z-\frac16z^3+\frac1{120}z^5+\cdots}{\frac13z^4-\frac1{30}z^6+\cdots}=3z^{-3}\left(1-\frac16z^2+\cdots\right)\left(1+\frac1{10}z^2+\cdots\right)\\
f(z) &= 3z^{-3}-\frac15z^{-1}+\cdots\end{align*}
for a residue of $-\frac15$.

Now, let $C(N,M)$ be the rectangular contour with corners at $N\pi+iM$, $-N\pi+iM$, $-N\pi-iM$, and $N\pi-iM$, for some large $M$ and large integer $N$. Define $I(N,M)=\int_{C(N,M)} f(z)\,dz$.

On the vertical segments, note that $\cot(\pm N\pi + iy)=\frac{\cos \pm N\pi\cosh y}{i\cos \pm N\pi\sinh y}=\frac1{i\tanh y}$. This is greater than $1$ in absolute value, so $|z^2\cot z-z|>|z|^2-|z|$ on those segments. Estimating $|z|\ge N\pi$, we get an integral of at most $\frac{2M}{N\pi(N\pi-1)}$ in absolute value on each vertical segment.

On the horizontal segments, $\cot(x+iy)$ tends to $\mp i$ uniformly as $y\to\pm\infty$. If $M$ is large enough that we're within $\epsilon$, this gives $|f(z)|\le \frac{1}{(1-\epsilon)^2|z|^2-|z|}$. Estimating $|z|\ge M$, this lead to an integral of at most $\frac{2N\pi}{M(M(1-\epsilon)^2-1)}$ in absolute value on each horizontal segment.

As long as neither $M$ nor $N$ gets too far ahead of the other - say, $M=\pi N$ - these both tend to zero as $M$ and $N$ go to $\infty$ together. We have shown that $\lim_{N\to\infty} I(N,\pi N)=0$.

Now, we calculate that integral with residues. Inside the contour $C(N,\pi N)$, there are $2N-1$ poles: the pole at zero, the first $N-1$ positive roots $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{N-1}$ of $\tan x=x$, and their negatives $-x_1,-x_2,\dots,-x_{N-1}$. Therefore
$$I(N,\pi N) = 2\pi i\left(-\frac15 + \sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\frac1{x_k^2}+\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\frac1{(-x_k)^2}\right)$$
$$0 = 2\pi i\left(-\frac15 + 2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{x_k^2}\right)$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{x_k^2} = \frac1{10}$$

Connected : https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~saito/publications/saito_rayleighfunc.pdf

Answer (score 2):

**This is not an answer of mine** It is an image of a solution with a higher degree of generalization (with references to the original question) that I have found on AOS [Explanation : As AOS site is no longer active, I fear the link I give [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h447902p2521205) will be disactivated] (pseudo of the author : PolyaPal). This thread is as well mentionned by @jmerry.

Independant remark : function $f$ can be written using Bessel function $J_{3/2}$ (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3527919)).

[image]