# Infinite sum of reciprocals of squares of lengths of tangents from origin to the curve $y=\sin x$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, coordinate-systems

> Let tangents be drawn to the curve $y=\sin x$ from the origin. Let the points of contact of these tangents with the curve be $(x_k,y_k)$ where $x_k\gt 0; k\ge 1$ such that $x_k\in (\pi k,  (k+1)\pi)$ and $$a_k=\sqrt {x_k^2+y_k^2}$$ (Which is basically the distance between the corresponding point of contact and the origin i.e. the length of tangent from origin)  .

---

I wanted to know the value of

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{a_k ^2}$$

Now this question has just popped out in my brain and is not copied from any assignment or any book so I don't know whether it will finally reach a conclusion or not.

---

I tried writing the equation of tangent to this curve from origin and then finding the points of contact but did not get a proper result which just that the $x$ coordinates of the points of contact will be the positive solutions of the equation $\tan x=x$

On searching internet for sometime about the solutions of $\tan x=x$ I got two important properties of this equation.  If $(\lambda _n)_{n\in N}$ denote the roots of this equation then

> $$1)\sum_n^{\infty} \lambda _n \to \infty$$ $$2)\sum_n^{\infty} \frac {1}{\lambda _n^2} =\frac {1}{10}$$

But were not of much help.

I also tried writing the points in polar coordinates to see if that could be of some help but I still failed miserably.

I could not think of any method so any other method would be openly welcomed.

Any help would be very beneficial to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit:**

On trying a bit more using some coordinate geometry I found that the locus of the points of contact is $$x^2-y^2=x^2y^2$$

Hence for sum we just need to find $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {\lambda _k ^2 +1}{\lambda _k ^2 (\lambda _k ^2 +2)}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{\lambda _k ^2} -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{\lambda _k ^2 (\lambda _k ^2 +2)}=\frac {1}{10} -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{\lambda _k ^2 (\lambda _k ^2 +2)}=\frac {1}{10} -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{2\lambda _k ^2} +\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{2(\lambda _k ^2 +2)} =\frac {1}{20}+\frac {1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{\lambda _k ^2 +2} 
 $$

Now for the second summation I did think about it to form a series but for the roots to be $\lambda _k^2 +2$ we just need to substitute $x\to \sqrt {x−2}$ in power series of $\frac {\sin x-x\cos x}{x^3}$ and then get the result but it was still a lot confusing for me.

Using $x\to\sqrt {x-2}$ in the above power series and using  [*Wolfy*](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=power+series+of+%28sin+%28%E2%88%9A%28x-2%29%29-+%28%E2%88%9A%28x-2%29%29*cos+%28%E2%88%9A%28x-2%29%29%29%2F%28%E2%88%9A%28%28x-2%29%C2%B3%29%29) I have got a series. So we need ratio of coefficient of $x$ to the constant term so is the value of second summation equal to
$$\frac {5\sqrt 2\sinh(\sqrt 2)−6\cosh(\sqrt 2)}{4(2\cosh(\sqrt 2)−\sqrt 2\sinh(\sqrt 2))}?$$

Is this value correct or did I do it wrong?

I would also like to know if there is some other method to solve this problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The points of contact are where the tangent to $y=\sin(x)$, which has a slope of $\cos(x)$, has the same slope as the line from the origin,  $\frac{\sin(x)}x$. Thus, we are looking at the points where $x_k=\tan(x_k)$.

The square of the length of the line from the origin is $x_k^2+\sin^2(x_k)=\frac{x_k^4+2x_k^2}{x_k^2+1}$. Therefore, the sum we are looking for is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x_k^2+1}{x_k^4+2x_k^2}\tag1
$$

---

The residue of $f(z)=\frac1{\tan(z)-z}-\frac1{(z^2+2)(\tan(z)-z)}$ where $z\ne0$ and $\tan(z)=z$ is
$$
\frac1{z^2}-\frac1{z^4+2z^2}=\frac{z^2+1}{z^4+2z^2}\tag2
$$

Thus, the sum of all the residues of $f(z)$ is $2$ times the sum we are seeking plus the residue of $f(z)$ at $z=0$, which is $\frac3{20}$, and the sum of the residues of $f(z)$ at $z=\pm i\sqrt2$, which is $-\frac1{2-\sqrt2\tanh(\sqrt2)}$

---

Note that the limit
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{\gamma_{k,\lambda}}f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z=\int_{\gamma_\lambda}f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z\tag3
$$
where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and the paths are
$$
\scriptsize\gamma_{k,\lambda}=[k\pi+i\lambda,-k\pi+i\lambda]\cup\underbrace{[-k\pi+i\lambda,-k\pi-i\lambda]}_{\le\frac{2\lambda}{k\pi}}\cup[-k\pi-i\lambda,k\pi-i\lambda]\cup\underbrace{[k\pi-i\lambda,k\pi+i\lambda]}_{\le\frac{2\lambda}{k\pi}}\tag4
$$
and
$$
\gamma_\lambda=(\infty+i\lambda,-\infty+i\lambda)\cup(-\infty-i\lambda,\infty-i\lambda)\tag5
$$
and $2\pi i$ times the sum of all the residues of $f(z)$ is
$$
\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\int_{\gamma_\lambda}f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z=-2\pi i\tag6
$$

$(6)$ means the sum of the residues of $f(z)$ over all singularities is $-1$. This is $2$ times the sum we are looking for plus $\frac3{20}-\frac1{2-\sqrt2\tanh(\sqrt2)}$

---

Therefore,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x_k^2+1}{x_k^4+2x_k^2}
&=-\frac{23}{40}+\frac1{4-2\sqrt2\tanh\left(\sqrt2\right)}\\
&=0.097374597898595746715
\end{align}
}\tag5
$$

---

**Numerical Check**

Note that each of the roots is a little less than an odd multiple of $\frac\pi2$:

$x_1=4.4934094579090641753\approx\frac{3\pi}2$
$x_2=7.7252518369377071642\approx\frac{5\pi}2$
$x_3=10.904121659428899827\approx\frac{7\pi}2$
$x_4=14.066193912831473480\approx\frac{9\pi}2$

Thus, we can under-approximate the sum using
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x_k^2+1}{x_k^4+2x_k^2}
&\approx\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(2k+1)^2\pi^2/4+1}{(2k+1)^4\pi^4/16+(2k+1)^2\pi^2/2}\\
&=0.092481600740508343614
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Excellent approach.  Mind blowing (+1). Thanks for accepting my request to solve the question.

Comment: Sir, could you please lend me some help over this problem- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3145071/limit-of-a-function-given-the-recurrence-relation

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to original question**

Simple bound $\pi k\leq a_k \leq \sqrt{\pi^2(k+\frac12)^2+1}$ shows that $\dfrac{a_k}{a_{k+1}}\to 1$.
So both sums diverge.

**Answer to modified question**

Again, (1) diverges.
(2) also diverges since squaring the ratio doesn't change $\to 1$.
(3) converges since you have $\pi k<\lambda_k=x_k<a_k$ giving $\dfrac{1}{a_k^2}\leq\dfrac{1}{\lambda_k^2}\leq\dfrac{1}{k^2}$.  This is of course a very loose bound.

**Finding $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\lambda_k^2+2}$ for use in $\sum a_k^{-2}$**

Recall one way of finding $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\lambda_k^{-2}=\frac{1}{10}$ is write down the series expansion of
$$
\sin x-x\cos x
$$
and set that to zero, reading off the lowest terms
$$
x^3\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{x^2}{30}+\frac{x^4}{840}+\dots\right)=0
$$
and after cancelling $x^3$ factor in front, you read off $\dfrac{1/30}{1/3}$ in a reciprocal Viete's formula way (except to make it rigourous you need to do it properly with infinite products, but that's another story).

So now we want to do this with $\lambda_k^2+2$.  You want to construct a series whose roots are $\lambda_k^2+2$  The simplest heuristic way is to use the full series expansion above (ignoring the $x^3$) and try to express it as a power series in $x^2+2$, and read off the sum of reciprocals of roots.

Comment: Oh so sorry I didn't reread my question.  I had to make a few edits so did it now. You can check the sequences now.

Comment: Simplified the answer to original question, which also answers the modified questions.

Comment: So I must try finding the answer to the third Sum right?

Comment: I suspect using the infinite product representation and nasty binomial expansion could work, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: I just added an edit to the question. Could you please give it a look and some hints to proceed further

Comment: Updated answer.  In the end you will have some sin(2) and cos(2) lyting around.

Comment: I did think about it to form a series but for the roots to be $\lambda _k ^2+2$ we just need to substitute $x\rightarrow \sqrt {x-2}$ in your series and then get the result but it would still be a lot confusing for me.  Could you please extend and try to elaborate your answer as in this case if it's possible for you.

Comment: Yes, that is one way to do it.  Then you need to expand all those (x-2)^(whatever) appearing and get the coefficient of constant term and that of $x$ (note every term in the original series will contribute, so you really need to write down the explicit series for $\dfrac{\sin x-x\cos x}{x^3}$).

Comment: Using $x\to \sqrt {x-2}$ using [_Wolfy_](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=power+series+of+%28sin+%28√%28x-2%29%29-+%28√%28x-2%29%29*cos+%28√%28x-2%29%29%29%2F%28√%28%28x-2%29³%29%29) I have got a series. So we need ratio of coefficient of $x$ to the constant term so is the value of second sum( where I need sum of reciprocals of $\lambda _k ^2 +2$) equal to $$\frac {5\sqrt 2 \sinh (\sqrt 2)- 6\cosh (\sqrt 2)}{4(2\cosh (\sqrt 2)-\sqrt 2 \sinh (\sqrt 2))}$$?