# Another interesting property of $y=2^{n-1}\prod_{k=0}^n \left(x-\cos{\frac{k\pi}{n}}\right)$: product of arc lengths converges, but to what?

Tags: limits, polynomials, circles, infinite-product, arc-length

Here is the curve $y=2^{n-1}\prod\limits_{k=0}^n \left(x-\cos{\frac{k\pi}{n}}\right)$, shown with example $n=8$, together with the unit circle centred at the origin.

[image]

Call the arc lengths between neighboring roots $l_1, l_2, l_3, ..., l_n$.

> What is the exact value of $L=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\prod\limits_{k=1}^n l_k$ ?

Desmos suggests that $L$ exists and is approximately $2.94$. Maybe $\frac{8}{e}$ ?

**Context**

I have studied this curve, and found that it has several interesting properties.

- The curve is tangent to the unit circle at $n$ points, which are uniformly spaced around the circle.
- The magnitude of the gradient at each root inside the circle is $n$; the magnitude of the gradient at $x=\pm1$ is $2n$.
- The total area of the regions enclosed by the curve and the *x*-axis is $1$.
- As $n\to\infty$, the volume of revolution of those regions about the *x*-axis approaches $\frac{1}{2}$ of the volume of the unit sphere, and the volume of revolution of those regions about the *y*-axis approaches $\frac{1}{\pi}$ of the volume of the unit sphere.
- As $n\to\infty$, if the curve is magnified so that the average area of those regions is always $2$, then the product of those areas approaches $4\cosh^2{\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi^2-8}}{2}\right)}\approx6.18$, as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4472892/398708).

I recently discovered that the product of arc lengths between neighboring roots seems to converge to a positive number as $n\to\infty$. Hence, my question.

(If you know any other interesting properties of this curve, feel free to add them in the comments.)

**My attempt**

The part of the curve inside the circle can be expressed as $y=-\sqrt{1-x^2}\sin{(n\arccos{x})}$. So

$$L=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\prod\limits_{k=1}^n \int_{\cos{\frac{k\pi}{n}}}^{\cos{\frac{(k-1)\pi}{n}}}\sqrt{1+\left(n\cos{(n\arccos{x})+\frac{x\sin{(n\arccos{x})}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}\right)^2}dx$$

I do not know how to evaluate this limit. I tried taking the log of the product, without success. I tried to approximate each integral as areas of triangles (hoping that that approximation would become equality with the limit) and a rectangle at the bottom, multiplying each triangle's area by $\frac{4}{\pi}$ (which is the ratio of areas under sine or cosine to the area of an inscribed triangle), but that resulted in a different limit.

EDIT

Further numerical analysis strongly suggests that $L=\frac{8}{e}$. I noticed that when $n$ doubles, the ratio of the two products is a certain number (which is close to $1$), and when $n$ is doubled again, the ratio's distance to $1$ is approximately halved. So then I projected that the product indeed approaches $\frac{8}{e}$. (I don't have Mathematica; anyone who has it is welcome to confirm this.)

I have simplified the expression of $L$. Letting $x=\cos{\frac{u}{n}}$, and ignoring the $1$ in the $\sqrt{1+(...)^2}$ (I think this is OK since $n\to\infty$), we get

$$L=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\prod\limits_{k=1}^n \int_{k\pi}^{(k-1)\pi}\sqrt{\left(n\cos{u}+(\sin{u})\cot{\frac{u}{n}}\right)^2}\left(-\frac{1}{n}\sin{\frac{u}{n}}\right)du$$

$$\space{}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\prod\limits_{k=1}^n \int_{(k-1)\pi}^{k\pi}\left|(\cos{u})\sin{\frac{u}{n}}+\frac{1}{n}(\sin{u})\cos{\frac{u}{n}}\right|du$$

So why is this equal to $\frac{8}{e}$ ?

Comment: My first try, which might well fail to produce any tangible result, is to try to use the general formula that $$\frac{\cos(a+b) + \cos(a-b)}{2} = \cos(a)\cos(b).$$  I would try to combine this approach with [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), which provide the pertinent coefficients of a polynomial, when the roots of that polynomial are known.

Comment: Re previous comment, also, there are symmetrical considerations around (for example) $$\sum_{k=0}^n \cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right).$$  For example, in general, $\cos(\theta) + \cos(\pi - \theta) = 0.$

Comment: Maybe, WA can find the antiderivative...

Comment: I think that the product of $(x-\cos\frac{\pi k}{n})$ is th Chebyshov's polynomial ()up to some constants, is that correct?

Comment: @richrow The curve in my question is the product of $(x^2-1)$ and a [Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind](https://archive.lib.msu.edu/crcmath/math/math/c/c243.htm#:~:text=Chebyshev%20Polynomial%20of%20the%20Second%20Kind%20A%20modified,develop%20four-dimensional%20Spherical%20Harmonics%20in%20angular%20momentum%20theory.).

Comment: **TeX:** instead of [ab]using `\dfrac` (which results in mixed-height math, and uneven vertical spacing), I suggest you to use *display-style math* when appropriate (i.e., use `$$...math...$$`, not `$...math...$`).

Comment: @metamorphy OK, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is closely related to computing the discriminant of Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind, found in literature (e.g., see G. Szegő [*Orthogonal polynomials*](https://books.google.com/books?id=3hcW8HBh7gsC), theorem $6.71$).

I'm going an elementary way here. Denote $x_{n,k}=\cos(k\pi/n)$ for $0\leqslant k\leqslant n$, so that $$S_n(x)=2^{n-1}\prod_{k=0}^n(x-x_{n,k})$$ is our polynomial. Then "ignoring the $1$ in the $\sqrt{1+(\dots)^2}$" amounts to saying that $l_k:=l_{n,k}$ is approximately twice the supremum of $\big|S_n(x)\big|$ on $x_{n,k-1}<x<x_k$; more precisely, we have $$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n l_{n,k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n\color{LightGray}{\Big[}2\sup_{x_{n,k-1}<x<x_{n,k}}\big|S_n(x)\big|\color{LightGray}{\Big]}=\lim_{n\to\infty}2^n\prod_{k=1}^n \big|S_n(x_{n,k}')\big|,$$ where $x_{n,k}'$ (for $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$) are the roots of $S_n'(x)$.

From [properties of resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Definition), we know that if $f$ is a polynomial of degree $d$, with leading coefficient $a$, roots $x_{d,k}$ for $1\leqslant k\leqslant d$, and roots of its derivative $x'_{d,k}$ for $0<k<d$, then $$\prod_{k=1}^{d-1}f(x_{d,k}')=\frac1{d^d a}\prod_{k=1}^d f'(x_{d,k}).$$

In our case $d=n+1$ and $a=2^{n-1}$, so that $$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2L_n}{(n+1)^{n+1}},\qquad L_n=\prod_{k=0}^n\big|S_n'(x_{n,k})\big|.$$

From $S_n(\cos t)=-\sin t\sin nt$ we get $S_n'(\cos t)=n\cos nt+\cot t\sin nt$, hence $$S_n'(1)=2n,\quad S_n'(-1)=2n(-1)^n,\quad S_n'(x_{n,k})=n(-1)^k\quad(0<k<n)$$ and $L_n=4n^{n+1}$, thus $L=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}8/(1+1/n)^{n+1}=8/e$ as claimed.

Comment: amazing. This takes me back to when I read Polya and Szego's famous Analysis book.

Answer (score 2):

A simple parameterization of the curve is given by

$$x = \cos \frac tn, \quad y = -{\sin t \sin \frac tn}, \quad 0 < t < nπ.$$

If we could approximate the arc length of the $k$th lobe $(k - 1)π < t < kπ$ by twice its height at $t = \frac{(k - 1/2)π}{n}$ (the point of tangency with the circle), we’d get

$$\prod_{k = 1}^n l_k ≈ \prod_{k = 1}^n 2\sin \frac{(k - \frac12)π}{n}.$$

That product equals $2$.  (Proof: observe that $z^n + 1 = \prod_{k = 1}^n (z - e^{2i(k - 1/2)π/n})$, because these monic polynomials have the same roots; substitute $z = 1$ and take absolute values.)

Unfortunately, as I think you’ve already observed, this approximation isn’t good enough.  For $k$ close to $1$ or $n$, the lobe shoots significantly past the tangency point before turning back toward the $x$ axis.  However, we can try to correct the approximation as follows.

If we translate the $k$th lobe by $(-1, 0)$ and scale it by a factor of $n$, we get

$$x = n\left(\cos \frac tn - 1\right), \quad y = -n \sin t \sin \frac tn.$$

As $n → ∞$, this approaches

$$x = 0, \quad y = -t \sin t,$$

with the arc length converging as $O(n^{-2})$.  This limiting arc length is

$$\max_{(k - 1)π < t < kπ} 2\lvert t \sin t\rvert = 2\lvert r_k\sin r_k\rvert,$$

where $r_k$ is the $k$th positive root of $r \cos r + \sin r = 0$.  But we’ve underestimated it as

$$2n \sin \frac{\left(k - \frac12\right)π}{n} \to 2\left(k - \frac12\right)π,$$

also converging as $O{(n^{-2})}$.  So we’ll need to correct the approximation by a factor of

$$\frac{\lvert r_k\sin r_k\rvert}{\left(k - \frac12\right)π}.$$

The corrections in lobes $k$ and $n + 1 - k$ are the same, so the overall correction tends to

$$L = 2\prod_{k = 1}^\infty \left(\frac{r_k \sin r_k}{\left(k - \frac12\right)π}\right)^2,$$

with overall error $O(n^{-1}) → 0$.  We can compute $L ≈ 2.94303552937$, whose proximity to $\frac 8e$ is extremely striking, although it’s hard to confirm since $r_k$ don’t seem to have a closed form.

Comment: Thanks, you have simplified the problem. This is interesting: $a_k$ doen't seem to have a closed form, but their infinite product (almost certainly) simplifies beautifully to $\frac{2}{\sqrt{e}}$.

Comment: I am almost certain that this can indeed be evaluated. $r_k$ do not have a closed form; however, they are solutions to $x +\tan x = 0$ and there are some neat identities involving their roots. For example, their square sum of the positive roots of a similar equation:
$$\tan x  = x$$ 
 turns out to be $\dfrac{e^2-7}{4}$, as demonstrated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3139642/all-positive-solutions-of-tan-x-x?noredirect=1)

Comment: @dezdichado Yeah, I’m starting to suspect it’s possible. (The equation is $\tan x = -x$ though.)